# Is it possible to show <datalist> autocomplete only after 3 chars entered?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a datalist with values in it (AD API - Users).
It shows all users after you clicked in the datalist field.
But I want that the autocomplete only shows up after 3 letters are entered.

**My code:**

```
<label> <input placeholder="Organisator" id="name" list="users" name="mitarbeiter" required /> </label>
<datalist id="users" class="dle" >
    <?php
    for ($i=0; $i<$counts; $i++) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$AllData[$i]["mail"][0].'">'.$AllData[$i]["cn"][0].'</option>'; 
    }
    ?>
</datalist>
```

I think it should be done with js.

Is it even possible? And how?

Answer (score 0):

You should use and modify "input" and don`t use "datalist".